# How can I change property value of an object after executing eventListener

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties, state

So, I wanna change property used from 0 to 1 when it's used, but when I do

```
function x() {     
    const array = [{
                    name: x,
                    surname: y,
                    used: 0
                   },{
                    name: c,
                    surname: b,
                    used:0
                   },{
                    name: f,
                    surname: g,
                    used: 0
                  }]
       
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)
    if (array[randomNumber].used === 0) {
                array[randomNumber] = { ..., used: 1 };
        }}
```

when I get same object again it will still be 0 for used even though it got trough if statement.

I also tried:

```
function x() {     
    const array = [{
                    name: x,
                    surname: y,
                    used: 0
                   },{
                    name: c,
                    surname: b,
                    used:0
                   },{
                    name: f,
                    surname: g,
                    used: 0
                  }]
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)
    if (array[randomNumber].used === 0) {
                array[randomNumber].used = 1;
        }}
```

and that also gives 0 when called again, I don't know how to make something like a state from React in vanilla JS, is there some way for it to remember that I changed the value?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: Thank you form mentioning it, I answered it, the problem was that my array was inside same function that changed the state

Answer (score 0):

It was simple really, if else(that is now switch) was inside of function like this

```
    const array = [{
                    name: x,
                    surname: y,
                    used: 0
                   },{
                    name: c,
                    surname: b,
                    used:0
                   },{
                    name: f,
                    surname: g,
                    used: 0
                  }]

    function x() {

      const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)
      if (array[randomNumber].used === 0) {
                array[randomNumber].used = 1;
                console log(array[randomNumber])
        })
```

and all I needed to do is make my array global by putting it outside of the function like I did here. Before I called array inside of the function, and every time I called function my values inside object would restart because thy were inside of the called function.

Comment: You should put the original version in the question, so we can see the difference.

Comment: I totally forgot, thank you for reminding me :)